# Is my only solution here to write my own async .csv parsing function? Or is there a way to salvage this?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv

So I'm reading hundreds of gigabytes of data stored in csv files. To read these, I'm using a Node.js module [`csv-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser)  which works simply like this:

```
fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log(results)
  });
```

but I need to store every item in mongodb, which can only be done asynchronously. My storage is like this:

```
// part of the Storage class
store(data, path) {
  return this.db.collection('fs').insertOne({
    path,
    data
  });
}
```

and then used with `csv-parser` like so:

```
const Storage = require.main.require('../js/classes/storage.js');
const storage = new Storage();
fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', async (data) => {
     await storage.store(data.pathName, data)
  })
  .on('end', () => {
     console.log("done");
  });
```

This code runs and starts loading into the database, but as I knew it would when I noticed this dilemma whilst writing this code, the `storage.store` func is obviously building up more and more unfulfilled promises since mongodb's `insertOne` can't keep up with `pipe` and eventually the program runs out of memory and crashes, like so:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[38856:000002755A720C70]   213027 ms: Scavenge 2042.7 (2050.2) -> 2042.1 (2050.4) MB, 4.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.247, current mu = 0.052) allocation failure
[38856:000002755A720C70]   213052 ms: Scavenge 2042.9 (2050.4) -> 2042.2 (2050.4) MB, 4.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.247, current mu = 0.052) allocation failure
[38856:000002755A720C70]   213076 ms: Scavenge 2043.1 (2050.4) -> 2042.5 (2050.9) MB, 4.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.247, current mu = 0.052) allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 00007FF70FA74DDD]
Security context: 0x038c95b808d1 <JSObject>
    1: parseLine [0000004EA78C3D49] [C:\Users\jonat\..proj path ..\node_modules\csv-parser\index.js:~91] [pc=0000013B01E5E861](this=0x02039a40ffd9 <Transform map = 000002262F7C3279>,0x005073d185a1 <Uint8Array map = 0000008B9F9A4389>,86184,86300)
    2: _transform [0000004EA78C3E29] [C:\Users\jonat\..proj path ..\node_modules\csv-parser\...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Writing Node.js report to file: report.20200605.012732.38856.0.001.json
```

Is my only solution here to write my own async .csv parsing function? Or is there a way to salvage this? It's really not that hard to write a csv parser, but laziness is a programmer's best friend, the less original code written to achieve the same desired result, the better. Maybe I can learn something new here.

Comment: I tried to parse the stack overflow database in node (many gigs of XML). It was extremely slow and I was having to work around memory issues. Given it was a one time thing I switched to python. It was 100x to 1000x faster and I got my task done in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. As in the docs on `csv-parser`, `neat-csv` is the solution for async, used as follows;

```
const neatCsv = require('neat-csv');
const csv = 'type,part\nunicorn,horn\nrainbow,pink';
(async () => {
    console.log(await neatCsv(csv));
    //=> [{type: 'unicorn', part: 'horn'}, {type: 'rainbow', part: 'pink'}]
})();
```